# How to avoid redirect loop in spring web mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
public class ValidateSession extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    //before the actual handler will be executed
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {    
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if(session.getAttribute("user")==null){
            /*ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/login/index");
            throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(mav);*/
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("redirect:/login/index.mars");
            throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(mav);           
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

In my case if session is expired then user can't access my application, but i am stuck with redirection loop. although i have tried many possible ways but not luck :(

Answer (score 2):

Don't associate the `ValidateSession` handler with the `login/index.mars` request. [Use mvc interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors). Exclusions possible since 3.2, I think.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/yourpath/*"/>
        <exclude-mapping path="/login/index.mars"/>
        <bean class="org...ValidateSession " />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Thanks Nim, but interceptor is not working with path="/*", any idea how can i enable interceptor for whole application.

Comment: Its working fine by adding <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
<mvc:exclude-mapping path="/login/**"/>
<mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**"/>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but thought it may be of help since none of the above worked for me.

In the class implementing HandlerInterceptor:

```
 response.sendRedirect("login?logout=true");
```

then in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap modelmap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession httpSession, @RequestParam(required = false) String logout, @RequestParam(required = false) String reason, @RequestParam(required = false) String message) {
    if (reason != null && MvcStatics.ERROR_MAP.get(reason) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        errors.add(MvcStatics.ERROR_MAP.get(reason));
        modelmap.addAttribute("errors", errors);
    }

    if (logout != null && logout.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        httpSession.removeAttribute("loggedIn");
        httpSession.removeAttribute("user");
        httpSession.removeAttribute("token");
        modelmap.addAttribute("message", "You have successfully been logged out.");
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

i experienced the same issue. just remove the "redirect:" appended before "/login/index.mars"

```
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("redirect:/login/index.mars");
    //to this and you redirect ll works fine
    mav.setViewName("/login/index.mars");
    throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(mav);
```